# Setting multiple fonts in tkinter textarea widget while using iterations

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am currently creating a project in tkinter which involves the use of textarea widget .
I want to set multiple fonts in the text area widget , but the only problem is that , i am using iterations , so I can't figure it out  .

The code that concerns me :

```
for i in range(len(news_list)):
        txtarea.configure(font=("Bahnschrift", 20) )
        txtarea.insert(END, news_list[i]["title"] + "\n\n" )
        txtarea.configure(font=("Bahnschrift", 20) )
        txtarea.insert(END, "Description:" +  str(news_list[i]["description"]) + "\n\n" )
        txtarea.insert(END, "Read More at:" +  str(news_list[i]["url"]) + "\n\n" )
        txtarea.insert(END , "--------------------------------- " + "\n")
```

Desired Output :

[image: See how different lines have different fonts ?]

See how different lines have different fonts ?

The actual output  :
[image]

Can please somebody help me with this ? Also , since I am kind of new to Stackoverflow , you are most welcome to point out the mistakes I have made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `tag` for every piece of text:

```
import tkinter as tk

TEXT = [("mountain", 'title'),
        ("[maʊntən]", "monospaces"),
        ("a large natural elevation of the earth's surface rising abruptly from the surrounding level", 'normal')]

root = tk.Tk()
t = tk.Text(root)
t.pack()
t.tag_configure("title", font=("Bahnschrift bold", 20))
t.tag_configure("monospaces", font=("Lucida", 12))
t.tag_configure("normal", font=("Arial", 14))

for text in TEXT:
    t.insert(tk.END, f'{text[0]}\n', text[1])
tk.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works , but can you tell me how to modify it in my situation ?

Comment: What is `my situation`?

Comment: I meant to say as I mentioned in my code above , I am using an API , and using iterations to output the data . In my case , I cannot possibly know what the data is  going to be , so can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a fixed text to be displayed, then, you can use tags. For example, run the following code -

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tbox = tk.Text(root, height = 5, width = 20, font = ('Calibri', 15))
tbox.pack()

# adding text to the text box
tbox.insert(tk.END, "Hello\nWe are exited for \nspace exploration.")
#adding tags
tbox.tag_add('Tag1', '3.0',  '3.17')
tbox.tag_config('Tag1', font = ('Calibri', 20, 'bold'))

root.mainloop()
```

Note: the syntax of creating a tag is -

```
<text box object>.tag_add(<tag name>, <starting character>, <ending character>)
```